# Is it possible to 'backwards-reference' something from a require()'d file in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reference

First time SO user so forgive me if my question is not concise. Essentially, I've began work on a project that's nearing 2000 lines of code and I've now decided to refactor it into several files / modules.

My file previously resembled something like this:

```js
const data = {
    thingOne: "hello",
    thingTwo: "goodbye"
}

switch (command) {
    case 'hello':
        console.log(data.thingOne);
    break;
    case 'goodbye':
        console.log(data.thingTwo);
    break;
}
```

After splitting the code up, it resembles the following:

data.js

```js
module.exports = {
    thingOne: "hello",
    thingTwo: "goodbye"
}
```

functions.js

```js
module.exports = {
    hello: () => {console.log(data.thingOne)},
    goodbye: () => {console.log(data.thingTwo)}
}
```

main.js

```js
const data = require('data.js');
const functions = require('functions.js');
// ...
```

This obviously doesn't work, as 'data' means nothing inside functions.js, the most obvious 'fix' that I can see for this would be to simply include data.js inside functions.js, but if both functions.js and data.js are included in main.js, then this'd mean that the contents of data.js are essentially included twice, which seems like bad practice to me.

My question is, ultimately, how can I split my code up whilst still being able to reference variables as in the above example, but avoiding bad practice?

Comment: If you're just getting started with this codebase, I suggest you use [modern standard modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) (`import` / `export`) rather than [CommonJS modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) (`require`, `exports = `).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Just curious, what is an actual programming advantage to import/export over `require()` and `module.exports` in nodejs besides being the new thing?

Comment: @jfriend00 - Still having my morning tea, but off the cuff, for me: static resolution (unless you use `import()` :-) ), `ReferenceError` rather than `undefined` value if there are module cycles and you try to use something not uninitialized yet because of the cycle, common loading behavior/order across environments (really only matters for cycles I guess), strict by default, and top-level `await`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Agree on the cycle issues - that was a design mistake in the original nodejs to not make that throw as was not making strict by default.  What does static resolution give you if you're not using a bundler?  As for disadvantages, the kluge to get the equivalent of __dirname or __filename is a mess.  And, I've had more than one time that computed exports were useful which has to be replaced with a function call in ESM.  Really, I was just curious what the real advantages of ESM modules are in nodejs.  I just haven't seen much yet.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Yeah, `__dirname`/`__filename` is a mess and I'm a bit surprised it hasn't been dealt with yet via `import.meta` ([`url`](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_import_meta_url) is there so you can figure it out, but blech). What kind of computed exports do you mean? Top-level `await` makes exports based on environment-specific module specifiers possible (at the cost of full static resolution), but I think you probably mean something else. Maybe an issue I haven't run into yet?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Imagine you want a module that exports a shared `eventEmitter` so multiple other modules can get access to the same emitter.  With static exports, you can't do `new EventEmitter()` and then directly export that.  That's what I mean by computed exports.  There are, of course, work-arounds, but they involve less convenient code for both the module and the callers.  It appears to me like the ESM design was heavily influenced by the desire for bundlers to only have static exports (for static code analysis) and that sacrificed features that CJS modules have.

Comment: @jfriend00 - *"With static exports, you can't do `new EventEmitter()` and then directly export that."* Why not? `export const theEmitter = new EventEmitter(/*...*/);` or `export default new EventEmitter(/*...*/);`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - OK, I guess I'm wrong.  I thought you could only export static things like functions or constants.  `new EventEmitter()` is not a static thing.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Yeah, 'static resolution" does make it sound like that a bit. :-) But it refers to the shape of the modules (e.g., what they export/import) and module graph rather than the values of the exports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...then this'd mean that the contents of data.js are essentially included twice...

No, it doesn't. They're **used** twice, but only a single copy of the module is in memory; there aren't two copies of it. If you need the information you're exporting from `data.js` in more than one place, importing it in each of the places you need it is completely normal.